# How to enable TLS 1.1, 1.2 in IIS 7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

We want to support web browsers utilizing TLS 1.1 and 1.2, which has been apparently implemented by Microsoft, but is turned off by default.

So I went searching on Google and discovered some pages everyone seems to be following:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245030

https://www.derekseaman.com/2010/06/enable-tls-12-aes-256-and-sha-256-in.html

However! It doesn't appear to be working for me. I have set both DWORD vaules for DisabledByDefault and Enabled for TLS 1.1 and 1.2. I can confirm my client is attempting to communicate with TLS 1.2, but the server only responds with 1.0. I've restarted IIS, but it didn't change the situation.

Microsoft points out: "WARNING: The DisabledByDefault value in the registry keys under the Protocols key does not take precedence over the grbitEnabledProtocols value that is defined in the SCHANNEL_CRED structure that contains the data for an Schannel credential."

Well, that's very vague to me. I can't find anywhere where SCHANNEL_CRED is defined or set, all I can determine that it's a structure defined in a Microsoft library. That's my only guess for why this isn't work, yet I can't find enough information on it to determine if it is the true problem.

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious, but did you reboot the server after changing the registry?

Comment: Hmmm. In IIS Manager, I clicked "Restart" under 'Actions'.

Comment: As @ShaneMadden indicated, these changes are deeper than IIS, so you need to restart the system to make sure all the changes are applied.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Reboot.  Changes to Schannel settings do not take effect until the system is rebooted.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to make changes in Microsoft SChannel protocols and ciphers (including cipher ordering) is to use [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) which is a completely free tool that can be downloaded without any kind of annoying registration requirements.

The tool manipulates the registry keys under the covers however it does so in a controlled, proven and safe way. We use it regularly.

It is also worth noting that it can help in automation scenarios as it has a command line version in addition to a GUI version.

There is also a [blog](https://blog.nartac.com/) that discusses some of the changes and why they have been made. The tool tends to be kept up to date when SSL issues arise.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling TLS 1.1 and 1.2 requires a reboot. Disabling RC4 and DH is directly without restarting the server or services.

If i remember correctly, disabling SSLv2 and SSLv3 was also instantly effective.

Answer (score -1):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn786418.aspx

To enable the protocol, change the DWORD value to 0xffffffff.

Comment: to enable protocol is 0xffffffff or 1 ?

Comment: That link on this answer says the value must be 1, it doesn't mention fff... anywhere