# Can't disable TLS 1.0

Tags: windows, security, ssl

I'm working on Windows Server 2016 Standard and trying to disable TLS 1.0 and enable 1.1 and 1.2 with the [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/). However, whenever I disable 1.0 and keep 1.1 and 1.2 enabled, my IIS apps stop serving. I've rebooted the server after the changes.

I saw [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/314874/how-to-enable-tls-1-1-1-2-in-iis-7-5) but it's not quite what I'm trying to do. There's also [this fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in) but it doesn't apply to Server 2016.

My `Global.asax.cs` contains the following in the `Application_Start()`:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol &=
  ~(SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer by using the [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) tool. You run the tool with the following command to test if the server supports various versions of TLS (with help from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/638691/how-can-i-verify-if-tls-1-2-is-supported-on-a-remote-web-server-from-the-rhel-ce)):

> openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tls1_1

```
CONNECTED(00000150)
40400:error:1417118C:SSL routines:tls_process_server_hello:version too low:ssl\statem\statem_clnt.c:917:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
```

The server didn't have a good cert so it could only support TLS 1.0.